# Using d3 How can I create a smooth transition on my globe animation?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3.js, Javascript and specifically the function `d3.geoOrthographic` to create the globe.

I've created a globe and now i am trying to rotate it to certain countries.
e.g. starts in the "UK" then rotates to "China"

I am doing this on an interval by.

```
d3.interval( () => {
    projection.rotate(coOrdinates)

    path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection)
    map.selectAll("path")
      .attr("d", path)
})
```

it works which is great however the transition to the country is instant, it isn't smooth.

How can i include a smooth transition to each country?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transition and `tween` the `rotate` attribute, with [`d3.interpolate`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-interpolate):

```
d3.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .tween("rotate", function() {
    const r = d3.interpolate(point, coOrdinates);
    return function(t) {
      projection.rotate(r(t));
    };
  })
```

where `point` is the point you're rotating from.